Does $d\mathbb{Z}_{n}\cong \mathbb{Z}_{\frac{n}{d}}$ hold?
$\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a finite ring. For a divisor $d$ of $n$, $d\mathbb{Z}_{n}\cong \mathbb{Z}_{\frac{n}{d}}$ does hold? I think it's going to be true, I can't prove it.
I'd appreciate your help.

Here is a closely related query that, had I found it, marked this as a duplicate of.

If we view them as groups, then they are isomorphic (they are both cyclic groups of order $\frac{n}{d}$.
But as rings, they are not generally isomorphic. An easy set of counterexamples is to take $p\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$, which is a ring with zero multiplication, and $\mathbb{Z}_p$, which is a field.
Note that sometimes you do get ring isomorphisms. For example, $3\mathbb{Z}_6$ has two elements, $0$ and $3$, and $3\times 3 \equiv 3\pmod{6}$, so $3\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$; similarly, $2\mathbb{Z}_6$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$, with multiplicative identity given by $4$.
In this case, this follows because by the Chinese Remainder Theorem we have $\mathbb{Z}_6\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$, and we are just getting one of the two factors.
So more generally, if $d\mid n$ and $\gcd(d,\frac{n}{d})=1$, then we can write $\mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_d\times\mathbb{Z}_{\frac{n}{d}}$. Then
$$d\mathbb{Z}_n \cong d\mathbb{Z}_d\times d\mathbb{Z}_{\frac{n}{d}} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{\frac{n}{d}}.$$
On the other hand, if $\gcd(d,\frac{n}{d})\neq 0$, then there is no ring isomorphism between $d\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{\frac{n}{d}}$.
To see this, let $p$ be a prime that divides both $d$ and $\frac{n}{d}$. Write $n=p^rm$ with $\gcd(p,m)=1$, and write $d=p^sk$ with $k\mid m$ and $1\leq s\lt r$. Then $\mathbb{Z}_n\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^r}\times\mathbb{Z}_m$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and
$$d\mathbb{Z}_n \cong d\left(\mathbb{Z}_{p^r}\times\mathbb{Z}_{m}\right) \cong p^s\mathbb{Z}_{p^r}\times k\mathbb{Z}_{m}.$$
But this ring (or, as some call them, "rng") does not have an identity: if $(x,y)$ lies in this ring, then the $r$th power of $(x,y)$ has $0$ first coordinate; so the only idempotents have $0$ in the first component, and none of these elements can be an identity, since $s\lt r$ so there are elements with nonzero first component. So while $d\mathbb{Z}_n$ has no identity, $\mathbb{Z}_{\frac{n}{d}}$ does, so they cannot be isomorphic as rings.
Thus,

Theorem. Let $n,d$ be positive integers with $d\mid n$. Then $d\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is ring-isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{\frac{n}{d}}$ if and only if $\gcd(d,\frac{n}{d})=1$.

